# function to parse shortcode using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse shortcode using jquery regex. But there is a problem with regex. Here is my code for using shortcode.

```
function shortCode(b, c) {
    var e = /\[\S+(?:\s+[^="]+="[^"\]\s]+")+\]/g;
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        var f = e[i].split('=');
        if (f[0].trim() == b) {
            c = f[1];
            if (c.match(e) != null) {
                return String(c.match(e)).trim()
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

My shortcode should be like this.

```
<strike>[stack="hello" over="hi" flow="5"]</strike>
```

**Output code:**

```
$(".test strike").each(function () {
    var e = $(this),
        t = e.html(),
        a = t.toLowerCase(),
        o = shortCode(t, "stack"),
        s = shortCode(t, "over"),
        r = shortCode(t, "flow");
    if (a.match("getcode")) {
        e.replaceWith('<div>' + o + s + r +'</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd build a wee parser.

Comment: Yep, but I used [Ohm](https://ohmjs.org), a PEG parser. The grammar *(depending on actual needs)* is ~12 lines, allows extension points *(e.g., `[]` for divs, `{}` for spans)*, handles escaped quotes in the values, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [shortcode.js](https://github.com/nicinabox/shortcode.js) by nicinabox. This will help you to create wordpress like shortcode.